# October CMS Blog Plugin - Custom Categories Page

Tags: octobercms, octobercms-plugins

I am customizing my Blog plugin and have partial overrides set up for the Post, Posts, and Categories components in my theme. Currently my custom *items.htm* partial that is called into the component's ***default.htm*** has the code shown in my snippet.

[Screenshot of items.htm code for October CMS Blog Categories component](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TmdJ3.png)

I'm trying to show a categories page that summarizes all of the blog post categories used in the blog, and under each category shown any post that uses that category will be listed with a linked post title. Right now with the above code, the categories are showing up as they should, but ALL of my current test blog posts are being listed under each category. Is there a way to filer/alter that code to show only the posts under each category that use that category? I'm also including a screen capture to illustrate the current output on the front end. Thanks for any advice.

Answer (score 1):

Yes you can list post for each category

> use this snippet but make sure you add `post` page and its URL should look like this be `/post/:slug` [ here imp part is :slug ]

```
<ul class="cats">
{% for category in categories %}
    <li {% if category.slug == currentCategorySlug %}class="active"{% endif %}>
        <a href="{{ category.url }}">{{ category.name }}</a>
        <ul class="posts">
            {% for post in category.posts %}
                <li>
                    <a href="{{ post.setUrl('post', this.controller) }}">{{ post.title }}</a>
                </li>
            {% endfor %}
        </ul>
    </li>
{% endfor %}
</ul>
```

> we need to set post URL explicitly as it depends on the page name. you can use any name you want but that page should exist in CMS. here we use `blog` so we have created page `post` with URL `/post/:slug`

if any doubts, please comment.

Comment: Thanks Hardik, that actually worked. But of course once I got this page working, I discovered that I didn't really want to output the categories like this anyway, as many of my posts will have multiple categories so they will show up multiple times if I do a master category index page. I ended up just using the default plugin method of clicking on a blog post category takes you to the output of all the posts with that category, instead of some kind convoluted master category index page. That's a long way of saying that your suggestion helped me figure out what I needed. Thanks!

Comment: Yes, I was also about to suggest you that but I thought maybe you have some other idea :)  anyways I am glad it helped you :)